# Printing pair of a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Im new in python but always trying to learn.

Today I got this error while trying select a key from dictionary:

> print(data['town'])
> KeyError: 'town'

My code:

```
import requests


defworld = "Pacera"
defcity = 'Svargrond'

requisicao = requests.get(f"https://api.tibiadata.com/v2/houses/{defworld}/{defcity}.json")
data = requisicao.json()

print(data['town'])
```

The json/dict looks this:

```
{
  "houses": {
    "town": "Venore",
    "world": "Antica",
    "type": "houses",
    "houses": [
      {
        "houseid": 35006,
        "name": "Dagger Alley 1",
        "size": 57,
        "rent": 2665,
        "status": "rented"
      }, {
        "houseid": 35009,
        "name": "Dream Street 1 (Shop)",
        "size": 94,
        "rent": 4330,
        "status": "rented"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  "information": {
    "api_version": 2,
    "execution_time": 0.0011,
    "last_updated": "2017-12-15 08:00:00",
    "timestamp": "2017-12-15 08:00:02"
  }
}
```

The question is, how to print the pairs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the `town` object by accessing the `houses` field first, since there is nesting.

You want `print(data['houses']['town'])`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your first error, do

```
print(data["houses"]["town"])
```

(since it's `{"houses": {"town": ...}}`, not `{"town": ...}`).

To e.g. print all of the names of the houses, do

```
for house in data["houses"]["houses"]:
    print(house["name"])
```

Comment: Thx bro, this helped me, but I have two questions:

> for house in data["houses"]["houses"]:
    print(house["name"])

How can I print the "houseid" too?

In this example:

print(data["houses"]["town"])

If want print the "name" not in a loop, how can I pass?

Answer (score 0):

As answered, you must do data['houses']['town']. A better approach so that you don't raise an error, you can do:

```
houses = data.get('houses', None)
if houses is not None:
    print(houses.get('town', None))
```

`.get` is a method in a dict that takes two parameters, the first one is the key, and the second parameter is ghe default value to return if the key isn't found.
So if you do in your example `data.get('town', None)`, this will return None because town isn't found as a key in data.